# Calculate the function sin()

Tags: c, algorithm, pi, trigonometry

For my studies, I have to code an algorithm to calculate `sin()` with this function:

[image]

[image]

However, in my algorithm, I have to keep the value of X between 0 and Pi/2. So, I wrote my algorithm but all the results are wrong.

Here is my code:

```
double sinX(double x){
    double resultat = 0;
    int i;
    if(x < 0 || x > M_PI_2)
        x = fmod(x,M_PI_2);

    for(i = 1;i<=30;i++){
        resultat += -1 * ((x*x)/(2*i*(2*i+1)))*(pow(-1,i-1))*((pow(x,2*i-1))/(factorielle(2*i-1)));
    }

    return resultat;
}
```

I didn't find the reason. Can you help me?

Here the are few values of X and the result with fmod

```
1 / 1
2 / 0.429204
3 / 1.4292
4 / 0.858407
5 / 0.287611
6 / 1.28761
7 / 0.716815
8 / 0.146018
9 / 1.14602
10 / 0.575222
11 / 0.00442571
12 / 1.00443
13 / 0.433629
14 / 1.43363
15 / 0.862833
16 / 0.292037
17 / 1.29204
18 / 0.72124
19 / 0.150444
20 / 1.15044
```

and the result with the algorithm

```
1 / -0.158529
2 / -0.0130568
3 / -0.439211
4 / -0.101605
5 / -0.00394883
6 / -0.327441
7 / -0.0598281
8 / -0.000518332
9 / -0.234888
10 / -0.0312009
11 / -1.44477e-008
12 / -0.160572
13 / -0.0134623
14 / -0.443022
15 / -0.103145
16 / -0.00413342
17 / -0.330639
18 / -0.0609237
19 / -0.000566869
20 / -0.237499
```

Here is my "factorielle" definition

```
double factorielle(double x){
    double resultat = 1;
    int i;

    if(x != 0){
        for (i=2;i<=x;i++)
        {
            resultat *= i;
        }
    }
    else{
        resultat = 1;
    }

    return resultat;
}
```

And values :

```
1 / 1
2 / 2
3 / 6
4 / 24
5 / 120
6 / 720
7 / 5040
8 / 40320
9 / 362880
10 / 3.6288e+006
11 / 3.99168e+007
12 / 4.79002e+008
13 / 6.22702e+009
14 / 8.71783e+010
15 / 1.30767e+012
16 / 2.09228e+013
17 / 3.55687e+014
18 / 6.40237e+015
19 / 1.21645e+017
20 / 2.4329e+018
```

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you would share a few test cases and results

Comment: I didn't check the validity of your code, but you should read up on [range reduction](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=9)

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect.  sin(x) {for pi/2 < x < pi} <> sin (mod(x,pi/2))

Comment: Also, did your algorithm work without using fmod when the input was 0 < x < pi/2 ?  If not, then you have other problems.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't the formula be: pow(-1,i) * ((pow(x,(2*i+1) / factor(2*i + 1)))

Comment: How is your function `factorielle` defined? Does it give correct result (a 81 digit number) when called with arguments as high as 59.  The whole point of the algorithm seems to be to avoid calculating this big numbers.

Comment: The factorial function you have defined will not give precise factorials. That is one source of the incorrect answers

Comment: The factorielle function doesn't have any problem. I use it in other program. The results that factorielle() returns are correct. I gave few values that returns factorielle()

Comment: Try it with larger arguments. A double float only has 15-17 significant digits. 30 ! = 265252859812191058636308480000000

Comment: I agree with Terje D. that the way you are using the factorial is not good. A double precision number has about 17 significant digits. So your value for 20! is a bit off. And things will get worse from that. The whole point of making the development of the i-th from the (i-1)-th term is to minimize this problem. Your calculation uses no advantage of this. In you program you might use the first formula to begin with. What you should do is to store the (i-1)-th term and calculate the i-th term recursively. Also, avoid the function pow to calculate the term (-1)^(i-1). Just check if i is even.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of the second formula you show.  The idea is that you use that formula to compute each term in the sum *from the preceding term*, saving you from the need to use any `pow` or `factorial` calls.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double sinX(double x) {
  double term, total_so_far;
  int i;

  term = x;  /* First term in the expansion. */
  total_so_far = 0.0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    /* Add current term to sum. */
    total_so_far += term;
    /* Compute next term from the current one. */
    term *= -(x * x) / (2*i) / (2*i + 1);
  }
  return total_so_far;
}


int main(void) {
  /* testing */
  double x;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    x = i / 10.0;
    printf("sin(%f) is %f\n", x, sinX(x));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And the results of running this code, on my machine:

```
sin(0.000000) is 0.000000
sin(0.100000) is 0.099833
sin(0.200000) is 0.198669
sin(0.300000) is 0.295520
sin(0.400000) is 0.389418
sin(0.500000) is 0.479426
sin(0.600000) is 0.564642
sin(0.700000) is 0.644218
sin(0.800000) is 0.717356
sin(0.900000) is 0.783327
sin(1.000000) is 0.841471
```

That should give you reasonable results for the range `0` to `pi / 2`.  Outside that range you'll need to be a bit cleverer about the reduction you're using: simply reducing modulo `pi / 2` won't give correct results.  (Hint: it's safe to reduce modulo `2 * pi`, since the `sin` function is periodic with period `2 * pi`.  Now use symmetries of the `sin` function to reduce to the range `0` to `pi / 2`.)

---

**EDIT** An explanation of why the current code is giving incorrect results: apart from the flawed reduction step, in your sum you start with the term `i = 1`.  But the first term should be for `i = 0` (that's the `x` term, while the `i=1` term is the `-x^3 / 3!` term).  A quick and dirty fix is to remove the reduction step, and to initialise your `resultat` variable to `x` rather than `0`.  That should give you good results for small `x`, and then you can figure out how to replace the reduction step.  I'd be surprised if you were really intended to compute the answer using explicit factorial and power calls, though - I'm almost sure that you're expected to compute each term from the preceding one as described above.

Comment: This algorithm is very good. I tested it with values between 0 to pi/2 and with pi, 10 etc. It give the correct answer. But, I must use the other. I'm a little bit stuck

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  The reduction to `[0, pi/2]`, or the computation after that reduction?  I'd suggest first removing your `fmod` reduction and testing just with small values (e.g. `abs(x)` less than `1.0`).  Once you've got it working for small values you can look at getting the reduction correct again.

Comment: And if you want a quick fix for your current calculation code:  initialize `resultat` to `x` instead of `0`.  (Your `for` loop iterates over the second and subsequent terms; it leaves out the first.)  I doubt that that's the way your instructor intended you to proceed, though.

Comment: If you can read french, I can give you my instructions : http://www.legeekcafe.com/upload/img/4581image.png . Look at the end of the paper for the sin(x)

Comment: Interesting; thanks.  If I'm understanding correctly, I think that confirms my suspicions:  where it says "Attention, il ne faut pas recalculer chaque terme ...", it's suggesting computing each new term from the previous one rather than computing each term outright.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code:

1. `sin(x+k*π/2)` does not necessarily equal `sin(x)`
2. Your expression for the term is a little bit messed up. The instructions seem to suggest that you calculate the next term in the series from the previous term. Start with the value for `i=0` and then use the equation in your question to compute the next term in each iteration.

Comment: Concerning #1, simple use the _exact_ value of π.  I'll just get out an infinite text editor and paste it in.  After its _done_, Ill send it over. For now, this will have to do [Pi - 10 Million Digits](http://pi.karmona.com/) ;-)

Comment: More seriously, to dig deeper into #1, suggest Google K.C. Ng's "Good to the Last Bit".

Comment: @chux For single precision, you only need 60 digits at most to get your result to be "Good to the Last Bit."

Comment: 60 decimals digits sounds about right.  Would you agree 340-350 digits for a `double`?  I hope my math is better than my math humor.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I followed yours indications. Here is my final code :

```
double sinX(double x)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    double term_i = 1.0;
    int i = 2;

    x = fmod(x, 2*M_PI);

    for(i = 2; i<= 30; i+=2)
    {
        term_i = (-term_i * (x*x)) / (i*(i+1));
        result += term_i;
    }

    return x * result;
}
```

Comment: this one uses the library `<math.h>`  for the function `M_PI`, right?

Comment: @Jneven yes, M_PI is defined in math.h

Answer (score 0):

Idea about the number of terms with OP's posted answer.

As long as one performs some range limitation first, like `fmod()`, the number of terms needed can be reasonably determined dynamically.  (Uses 1 to 23 iterations for x: 0 to 2*pi.)

```
double sinX1(double x)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    double term_i = 1.0;
    int i = 2;

    x = fmod(x, 2*M_PI);

    // for(i = 2; i<= 30; i+=2)
    for(i = 2; ((1.0 + term_i) != 1.0); i+=2)
    {
        term_i = (-term_i * (x*x)) / (i*(i+1));
        result += term_i;
    }
    return x * result;
}
```