# Taylor Series to calculate cosine (getting output -0.000 for cosine(90))

Tags: c, precision, trigonometry, taylor-series

I have written the following function for the Taylor series to calculate cosine.

```
double cosine(int x) {
    x %= 360; // make it less than 360
    double rad = x * (PI / 180);
    double cos = 0;

    int n;

    for(n = 0; n < TERMS; n++) { 
        cos += pow(-1, n) * pow(rad, 2 * n) / fact(2 * n);
    }
    return cos;
}
```

My issue is that when i input 90 i get the answer -0.000000.  (why am i getting -0.000 instead of 0.000?)

Can anybody explain why and how i can solve this issue?
I think it's due to the precision of double.
Here is the main() :

```
int main(void){
int y;
//scanf("%d",&y);
y=90;
printf("sine(%d)= %lf\n",y, sine(y));
printf("cosine(%d)= %lf\n",y, cosine(y));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: One likely culprit is the printing routine, which you don't show. And don't make a variable named `cos` when including math.h.

Comment: What do you expect instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is you're inquiring about. The value of `cos(90)` is 0. `-0.000000` is essentially 0. BTW, there's a much more efficient way to calculate successive terms. Each term is just `-(rad * rad)/(2*n*(2*n-1))` multiplied by the previous term. So save the term value in each loop iteration for this purpose.

Comment: Use `%g` instead of `%f`, you will see to which value tends your result

Comment: Since `cos(90 + a little bit)` is `0 - a little bit`, this sort of thing is likely.  Your code is (probably) working fine.  "Never compare floating-point numbers for equality."  -0 is close enough to 0 for all practical purposes.

Comment: Why are you taking an `int` as argument?

Comment: Lundin, the printing routine has been added

Comment: Lurker, why am i getting -0.000 instead of 0.000?

Comment: An exact value of pi can't be represented as a `double`, hence your `rad` value isn't exactly 90 degrees (pi / 2), hence the Taylor series won't converge exactly on 0. Even if it would, there's no guarantee the number of terms you chose will make it tend to positive or negative zero. tldr : don't expect to get an exact value `0.0` out of this code - [floating point just doesn't work that way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Can you provide  your values of PI and TERM ? Also, Taylor series estimate a proximate value, which could be slightly ABOVE or BELOW "real" answer (0.0 in thise case). The '-0.000000' indicates that the estimate number is  between -1e-9 and (approximately) -1e-300.

Comment: @dash-o: “-0.000000” does not indicate the number is between -1e-9 and 1e-300. It could be exactly zero.

Comment: FNF, Use `printf("cosine(%d)= %lg\n",y, cosine(y));`  (g vs f) and report your output.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, while we do not know what PI and TERMS are using. I've tested with standard M_PI, and terms 1 to 20.  Th eoutput for TERMS=10 is-3.376e-13, which will display as '-0.000' when truncated by printf to 9 places. Using '%g' will show the 'real value'.

Comment: @dash-o: Nonetheless, an output of “-0.000000” does not indicate the number is between −1e−9 and −1e−300. `printf("%f", -0.);` will print “-0.000000”.

Answer (score 3):

It's totally expected that you will not be able to get exact zero outputs for cosine of *anything* with floating point, regardless of how good your approach to computing it is. This is fundamental to how floating point works.

The mathematical zeros of cosine are odd multiples of pi/2. Because pi is irrational, it's not exactly representable as a double (or any floating point form), and the difference between the nearest neighboring values that are representable is going to be at least pi/2 times `DBL_EPSILON`, roughly `3e-16` (or corresponding values for other floating point types). For some odd multiples of pi/2, you might "get lucky" and find that it's really close to one of the two neighbors, but on average you're going to find it's about `1e-16` away. So your input is *already wrong by `1e-16` or so*.

Now, cosine has slope +1 or -1 at its zeros, so the error in the output will be roughly proportional to the error in the input. But to get an exact zero, you'd need error smaller than the smallest representable nonzero double, which is around `2e-308`. That's nearly 300 orders of magnitude smaller than the error in the input.

While you coudl in theory "get lucky" and have some multiple if pi/2 that's really really close to the nearest representable double, the likelihood of this, just modelling it as random, is astronomically small. I believe there are even proofs that there is **no double** `x` for which the correctly-rounded value of `cos(x)` is an exact zero. For single-precision (`float`) this can be determined easily by brute force; for `double` that's probably also doable but a big computation.

As to why `printf` is printing `-0.000000`, it's just that the default for `%f` is 6 places after the decimal point, which is nowhere near enough to see the first significant digit. Using `%e` or `%g`, optionally with a large precision modifier, would show you an approximation of the result you got that actually retains some significance and give you an idea whether your result is good.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that when i input 90 i get the answer -0.000000. (why am i getting -0.000 instead of 0.000?)

- `cosine(90)` is not precise enough to result in a value of 0.0.  Use `printf("cosine(%d)= %le\n",y, cosine(y));`  (note the `e`) to see a more informative view of the result.  Instead, `cosine(90)` is generating a negative result in the range [-0.0005 ... -0.0] and that is *rounded* to `"-0.000"` for printing.

> Can anybody explain why and how i can solve this issue?

OP's `cosine()` lacks sufficient range reduction, which for *degrees* can be *exact*.

`x %= 360;` was a good first step, yet perform a better range reduction to a 90° width like [-45°...45°], [45°...135°], etc.

Also recommend: Use a Taylor series with sufficient terms (e.g. 10) and a good machine `PI`<sup>1</sup>.  Form the terms more carefully than `pow(rad, 2 * n) / fact(2 * n)`, which inject excessive error.

[Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386361/c-program-taylor-series-long-formula/33405682#33405682), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525208/2410359).

Other improvements possible, yet something to get OP started.

---

<sup>1</sup> `#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795`